# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.example.backendtest.Project

Tags: java, spring

I am using http post requests angular4 with spring boot and I need to send different Objects from angular to the backend that's why I am using the type object and then trying to cast this object to my java class (In my Example Project and User) but I am getting this exception.
this is my http post method:

```
@PostMapping("/project")
public void addProject(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> map) {
    Project project1 = (Project) map.get("project");
    System.out.println(project1.getName());
    List<User> users = (List<User>) map.get("users");
    System.out.println(users.get(0));
}
```

Comment: `map.get("project")` returns a List instead of an Project. Looks like you entered an array of objects instead of one object.

Comment: that's right, but how can I fix it ??

Comment: you can debug and check what 'map.get("project")' is returning and based on that you can figure out the fix for the same. Basically this error occurs if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map.

Comment: @SourourBlel Either fix it at the source, so the http request to the server to only add one object instead of an array, or cast `map.get("project")` to a list and get the object from the list. The first seems the best option IMO.

Comment: I need to get multiple objects with different types at the same time so I need to use the second option. and when I casted map.get("project") to a List I get this exception:  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestBody` injects a [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) (in case you mapped multiple things to `project`). So if you are certain that only one value will be mapped to `project`, you can just replace

```
@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> map
```

with

```
@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> map
```

and

```
Project project1 = (Project) map.get("project");
```

with

```
Project project1 = (Project) map.getFirst("project");
```